# how to use google analytics geo map

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i successfully created the linechart how many people visited my site from different countries. here is my code:

```
var API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
var TABLE_ID = 'ga:XXX';

gadash.configKeys({
  'apiKey': API_KEY,
  'clientId': CLIENT_ID
});

var chart1 = new gadash.Chart({
  'type': 'LineChart',
  'divContainer': 'country_visitors',
  'last-n-days':30,
  'query': {
    'ids': TABLE_ID,
    'metrics': 'ga:visits',
    'dimensions': 'ga:country'
  },
  'chartOptions': {
    height:600,
    title: 'Visitors from countries (Last 30 days)',
    hAxis: {title:'Date'},
    vAxis: {title:'Visits'},
    curveType: 'function'
  }
}).render();
```

but what i need is to show the data in geomap instead of linechart like it shows in dashboard when you log in google analytics account. i tried to change the type to GeoMap but it shows only the table not geo map. i also read the documentation on Visualization: Geomap. what i saw there is i need to give the data in an array and i don't have any idea how to do that. can anyone please help me with what i need? and one more thing when i was generating the line chart it asked me to authorize analytics, what should i do to view the analytics data without logging in. i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: not sure about the gadash library but check out the Google Embed api [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started?hl=en) that works for me and for the map its  `chart: {     type: 'GEO', ...` it may be the same here.

Comment: Did you get this working? Could you pls share how you solved this.